# How to add JSFiddle link without including code in Answer?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I face an issue while answering the question with JSFiddle link.

[image]

I used the same code as the questioner in the JSFiddle and it works for me.  I don't want to include the code in the answer as there is no modification. But the error didn't allow me to post.

Finally I added a code saying `No Change in code` and posted the answer.

Is there is any other way to post the link from fiddle without including the code?

Comment: Why? Code should be included in the post itself and not on any third-party sites. I guess you're not aware of [stack-snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "Your code is fine" is not an answer. Post it as a comment, instead. And flag the question to be closed.

Answer (score 5):

#### Your code is working fine in my environment

That means the issue is not reproducible or there is no issue in the code. Such questions should be closed as:

> **Off-topic**: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

#### I don't want to include the code

The code should be added in the post itself and not on any third-party sites. As the error message says, JSFiddle link can be only be added to posts as an accompaniment to the code.

Comment: Should also consider using [Stack-Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of JSFiddle links, like you [mention in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319173/how-to-add-jsfiddle-link-without-including-code-in-answer#comment323423_319173).